# Optimizing Django Text Field Lookup

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have a simple model for storing text objects:

```
class Text(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
```

I need `content` field to be unique. So, I created a custom unique index on it:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX text_md5 ON text_table (md5(content));
```

Now, I query for selecting specific rows:

```
Text.objects.get(content='sample text.')
Text.objects.filter(content__in=['text1', 'text2'])
```

And it is **very slow**. I want `postgres` to find text object using its content md5. What is the most elegant way for doing this in Django.

Also, I want to query this field with `contains` filter that is `LIKE` query:

```
Text.objects.get(content__contains='text')
```

What is the best **indexing solution** for optimizing these queries?

I know that full text search is another option. But, I don't need complicated search features.

Comment: What kind of text are you storing there? Are you sure you want a TextField (a blob) rather than a CharField (a varchar)?

Comment: I want to store short and long text contents, something like 1 to 1000 words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres 10 `hash index` makes text lookup queries very fast. So, I added this simple index:

```
CREATE INDEX text_hash ON text_table USING hash(content);
```

This index optimized text select queries without any change in my python code.